# Android Layout - list within a list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to Android and need help in creating the following layout:

[image]

I've gone through the example of using ListFragment and ArrayAdapter but in this scenario, I want to display a list within a list. How would I create a layout like this?

Comment: use expandable listview if you want to display list in a listview and extend the baseExpandableListAdapter to display your data to your desired type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ExpandableListView for this. The ExpandableListView is a List within a List:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Here is a nice tutorial which explains how to use it:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

For your design, you don't need to use ListView in ListView. Just use two different custom layout for ListView. One for title and other for subject data.

example:

for title layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

for data layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in your getView() from Adapter,

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Context context;

        if(object.isTitle() == true){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.title_layout, null);
            //implement title layout
        }
        else{
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.data_layout, null);
            //implement data layout
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: can you please add any example

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a list within a list for this. You can as well use a TableLayout and modify the TableRow elements according to your requirement. Infact, I would highly recommend it. Check out this link for an example :

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-table-layouts--mobile-4788

Cheers !